# Bulk populate private NuGet Gallery

Tags: nuget, nugetgallery

We have setup our own NuGet Gallery - https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery (NuGet.Server is no good for us as the performance is poor with our volume of packages).

Is there a way to bulk upload the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff Handley has a post here http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2012/12/13/Bulk-Publishing-NuGet-Packages.aspx where he has created PS module https://github.com/jeffhandley/JeffHandley.NuGetPS to help achieve this task.

hth